errorformat: Trailing characters. Cannot load Grepper output from a file into quickfix
I get Trailing characters error with set errorformat when trying to use quickfix:
This is a sample line from a file 20240527-grep.txt that I would load into quickfix. Note, I obtained this output from a Grepper command:
pages/20230817-Beyza-GG.md|19 col 3| - TODO #p/beyza: Takip edelim

This is the command to load the above file into quickfix:
cfile ~/prj/collabryio/cldocs/cllogseq/20240527-grep.txt

This is the output in quickfix:
|| pages/20230817-Beyza-GG.md|19 col 3| - TODO #p/beyza: Takip edelim

I set errorformat with the following commands but I get Trailing characters error:
set errorformat+=%f|%l col %c|%m
# E488: Trailing characters: col %c
set errorformat^=%f|%l col %c|%m
# E488: Trailing characters: col %c

Now, I load the file into quickfix again:
cfile ~/prj/collabryio/cldocs/cllogseq/20240527-grep.txt

Now the output in quickfix becomes empty totally:



Does this answer your question? https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/44564/10604

You have to escape the space   and the pipe |:
set errorformat+=%f\|%l\ col\ %c\|%m

You could be interested to the alternative form:
let &errorformat .= ',%f|%l col %c|%m'

